# regex comment matching code in java not working properly

Tags: java, regex

I have this code for Identifying the comments and print them in java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\/\\*((.|\n)*)\\*\\/)|\\/\\/.*");
        String code = "";
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(scan.hasNext())
        {
            code+=(scan.nextLine()+"\n");

        }
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(code);
        int nxtBrk=code.indexOf("\n");
        while(matcher.find())
        {

            int i=matcher.start(),j=matcher.end();
            if(nxtBrk<i)
            {
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
            System.out.print(code.substring(i,j));
            nxtBrk = code.indexOf("\n",j);

        }



    scan.close();
    }

}
```

Now when I try the code against this input

```
 /*This is a program to calculate area of a circle after getting the radius as input from the user*/  
\#include<stdio.h>  
int main()  
{ //something
```

It outputs right and only the comments. But when I give the input

```
 /*This is a program to calculate area of a circle after getting the radius as input from the user*/  
\#include<stdio.h>  
int main()  
{//ok
}  
/*A test run for the program was carried out and following output was observed  
If 50 is the radius of the circle whose area is to be calculated
The area of the circle is 7857.1429*/
```

The program outputs the whole code instead of just the comments. I don't know what wrong is doing the addition of that last lines.

EDIT: parser is not an option because I am solving problems and I have to use programming language . link https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ide-identifying-comments

Comment: Re "parser is not an option", not using a parser is not an option either unless you want to find spurious comments in `"/* A string, not a comment */"`, `"http://foo"`, `"/path/*.txt"  /* A file path */`.  You need to recognize all tokens that can contain comment boundaries to recognize comment boundaries correctly.

Comment: How can I do that in that website?

Comment: A parser most certainly is an option, especially as you only really need the lexer part (generally the simplest part if you've already got regular expression support available). Beware! This is quite a deep topic to get into properly; it was part of a second-year course back when I took CS (years ago…)

Comment: @Unbound, As Donal suggested, you can lex (tokenize) using a single regular expression and then filter out the matches that are not comment tokens.  For example, `Pattern.compile("(?:" + COMMENT_REGEX + ")|(?:" + STRING_REGEX + ")", ...)` where `STRING_REGEX = "\"(?:[^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*\"|'(?:[^'\\\\]|\\\\.)*'"`.  That way, quotes will match as string tokens which will effectively hide any apparent comment boundaries inside string tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern, shorn of its Java quoting (and some unnecessary backslashes), is this:

```
(/\*((.|
)*)\*/)|//.*
```

That's fine enough, except that it has just greedy quantifiers which means that it will match from the first `/*` to the *last* `*/`. You want non-greedy quantifiers instead, to get this pattern:

```
(/\*((.|
)*?)\*/)|//.*
```

Small change, big consequence since it now matches to the *first* `*/` after the `/*`. Re-encoded as Java code.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(/\\*((.|\n)*?)\\*/)|//.*");
```

(Be aware that you are very close to the limit of what it is sensible to match with regular expressions. Indeed, it's actually incorrect since you might have strings with `/*` or `//` in. But you'll probably get away with it…)

Answer (score 3):

Parsing source code with regular expressions is very unreliable. I'd suggest you use a specialized parser. Creating one is pretty simple using [antlr](http://www.antlr3.org/). And, since you seem to be parsing C source files, you can use the [C grammar](http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/1153358328744/C.g).